# Index was outside the bounds of array in graph plotting c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a graph between instant charge against time, and I'm getting this error:

> Index was outside the bounds of array

My code is below:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication19
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double max = 24000000, min = 23999999.85;
            double[] q = new double[9];
            int t = 0;
            for (t = 1; t <= 10; t++)
            {
                q[t] = (24 * Math.Pow(10, 6)) * Math.Exp(-t / (2000 * Math.Pow(10, 6)));
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, q[t]);
            }

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = max;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = min;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but am still having the same problem:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    double[] q = new double[9];
    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (t = 1; t <= 10; i++)
        {
            q[i] = (24 * Math.Pow(10, 6)) * Math.Exp(-t / (2000 * Math.Pow(10, 6)));
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, q[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Array indexes are 0 based. Start from 0 to 8. Note that `q` length is 9. So you should start from 0 to 8 NOT 1 to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index out of bounds means that your code is trying to write to an index that is higher than the highest index.

You have 2 problems in your code that cause this - you need to fix both before it will work.

**1. Fix `q`**

In your code you have an array `q` which has 9 indexes, from `0` to `8`, but it looks like you want 10: `new double[10]`.

**2. Fix the loop**

In your for look you loop from 1 to 10, but arrays start with index 0 (you have 10 indexes, from 0 to 9). You need `t` to start with 0, not 1.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication19
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double max = 24000000, min = 23999999.85;
            double[] q = new double[10]; // Fix q: length of 10
            for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++) // Fix loop: start at 0
            {
                int t = i + 1; // Fix loop: t and i need to have different values
                q[i] = (24 * Math.Pow(10, 6)) * Math.Exp(-t / (2000 * Math.Pow(10, 6)));
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, q[i]);
            }

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = max;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = min;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but still having an error of "Index was outside the bounds of array" at t = 10.
graph is showing only value from t = 1 to 9
but at t= 10 it is showing an error

Comment: Have you forgotten to change one of the `q[t]` to `q[i]`? Or is `t` supposed to start at 0 as well?

Comment: no i've changed all q[t] to q[i] and t is not supposed to start at 0 it should start from 1 to 10

Comment: while debugging it i saw that it is showing error of " Index was outside the bounds of the array" in my formula at t = 10

Comment: Hm.. Not sure if this is your problem, but I see a mistake in my for loop. `for (int i = 0; t < q.Length; i++)`, it should of course be `for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)`

Comment: when i tried to take t = i then it shows same error at the last value of t which is t = 9

Comment: i dont know why it is getting an error at last value of t ?
either it is 10 or 9

Comment: If you copy and paste all the code in my answer into your project, does it still not work for you?

Comment: Tried the code online (without the chart stuff) and it works: http://csharppad.com/gist/26886f0847f91c3deb9f

Comment: but i need to make a graph :/

Comment: First you must identify _where_ the error is. Try, in your code on your computer, to comment out all the lines beginning with `chart1`. If you still get the error, you have still not fixed one (or both) of the errors. If it does work, the something is wrong with the graph code, but not the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for loop it is much more standard to go from 0 to < q.Length.

That way you can change the length of your array and the for loop will still work.

```
        double[] q = new double[9];
        for (int t = 0; t < q.Length; t++)
        {
            q[t] = (24 * Math.Pow(10, 6)) * Math.Exp(-t / (2000 * Math.Pow(10, 6))); 
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, q[t]);               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your array can contain 10 elements since:

`double[] q = new double[9];`

when your for loop hits 10; it means you want to reach q[10] so it will result in Index was outside the bounds of array error.

you shouldn't increment your loop index more than 9.